# Is Aircrack-ng illegal?

Tags: linux, debian, aircrack-ng

I just found out about this Linux-based network toolset called Aircrack-ng. It’s pretty interesting, and I’m learning how to use it. But it just occurred to me that, like a lot of Linux programs, it’s developed in other countries, with different laws.

So my question is, is it illegal in America, specifically Ohio, to use this program? I mean, I know it has a legitimate purpose, but so does hemp.

I did do a Google search, and the only relevant result I found was a question on another site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn’t say it’s illegal — it’s a grey zone — but as long as you are only using it for educational purposes and on your own networks you are in the clear. As in, make sure you don’t get caught breaking into other people’s networks.

It does give a very good insight into how insecure wireless connections are.

If you need something to help you along a bit, try Grimwepa and Wifite.

Comment: The tool itself is not illegal and is used for penetration testing on your own network, or employer's network, if employed for that capacity.  Don't really think it's grey, though.  You're either using a legitimate tool for illegal means, or not.