# How to connect to a secured network

Tags: windows-10

I have searched online including youtube to know about how connect to a secured network(wifi) without knowing the key. But it seems there isn't a way to that.Is there a way to connect to a secured wifi using windows 10 operating system?If any how should go about it

Comment: This site does not condone nor help with breaking security systems of any sort.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/) web for more information about tools.
Aircrack-ng is a complete suite of tools to assess WiFi network security.

Check [this web](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers&DokuWiki=ibqj1ao2kch12jbkpnhaaec470) for details about your WiFi card and Windows drivers plus it might be handy to know local law about violating someone's private network ;]
 [In this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/234098/is-aircrack-ng-illegal) for example.